# How can i make small stock icons in my application?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, stock

i have a button in my application and i want it to have dimensions 23x23 pixels with stock icon 16x16 pixels.

I came up with:

```
closeButton = gtk.ToolButton(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE)
closeButton.set_size_request(23, 23)
```

but this code only changes size of button and not size of icon :/

How can i scale stock icon on my button? Is there are any small versions of stock items? Something like gtk.STOCK_SMALL_CLOSE?

EDIT
Here is sample program to test possibilities of creating small stock items

```
import gtk

class Tab(gtk.VBox):
    def __init__(self, caption):
        gtk.VBox.__init__(self)
        self.Label = self.__createLabel(caption)
        self.show_all()

    def __createLabel(self, caption):
        hbox = gtk.HBox()
        label = gtk.Label(caption)
        hbox.pack_start(label, True, True)
        closeButton = gtk.ToolButton(self._getCloseIcon())
        hbox.pack_start(closeButton, False, False)
        hbox.show_all()
        return hbox

    def _getCloseIcon(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class TabWithNormalIcons(Tab):
    def __init__(self, caption):
        Tab.__init__(self, caption)

    def _getCloseIcon(self):
        return gtk.STOCK_CLOSE

class TabWithImage16Icons(Tab):
    def __init__(self, caption):
        Tab.__init__(self, caption)

    def _getCloseIcon(self):
        return gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, 16)

class TabWithSmallToolbarIcons(Tab):
    def __init__(self, caption):
        Tab.__init__(self, caption)

    def _getCloseIcon(self):
        return gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR)

class TabWithMenuIcons(Tab):
    def __init__(self, caption):
        Tab.__init__(self, caption)

    def _getCloseIcon(self):
        return gtk.image_new_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)

class App(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Window.__init__(self, gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.connect('destroy', lambda event: gtk.main_quit())
        self.set_default_size(640, 480)
        notebook = gtk.Notebook()
        tabNumber = 1

        #Icon normal sizes
        for i in range(3):
            tab = TabWithNormalIcons('Tab %s' % str(tabNumber))
            notebook.append_page(tab, tab.Label)
            tabNumber += 1

        #Icons with 16 pixel Image
        for i in range(3):
            tab = TabWithImage16Icons('Tab %s' % str(tabNumber))
            notebook.append_page(tab, tab.Label)
            tabNumber += 1

        #Icons with small toolbar images
        for i in range(3):
            tab = TabWithSmallToolbarIcons('Tab %s' % str(tabNumber))
            notebook.append_page(tab, tab.Label)
            tabNumber += 1

        #Icons with menu images
        for i in range(3):
            tab = TabWithMenuIcons('Tab %s' % str(tabNumber))
            notebook.append_page(tab, tab.Label)
            tabNumber += 1
        self.add(notebook)
        self.show_all()

a = App()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

`set_size_request` only defines the minimum size you want a widget to have. So indeed, it doesn't scale children, and it also doesn't prevent it from growing when its children require this. And if it would, that wouldn't be what you want: it would still draw the large icon, but clip it to the button.

So what you do want, is to get your stock item with a different size. I think the easiest is to create a gtk.Image, where you can specify the stock size. Then insert that Image widget into your button instead of the stock value.

So in code:

```
image = gtk.image_new_from_stock (gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR)
closeButton = gtk.Button ()
closeButton.add (image)
closeButton.set_size_request (23, 23)
```

Comment: Agree but, I would rather use something like `image = gtk.image_new_from_stock (gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.ICON_SIZE_SMALL_TOOLBAR)` than my own size if not absolutely neccesary.

Comment: Hmm, seems that it not working, my icons are not smaller :/ I edited my question and added simple test program.

Comment: While testing this, I noticed two things: 1. you can not specify numerical icon sizes such as 16, but only the constants gtk.ICON_SIZE_*. 2. There is magic in gtk.ToolButton which makes it ignore the given size (with the default from the theme, I suppose). So if you really want to override this, use a gtk.Button. Or do this because you aren't putting your buttons in a toolbar. If you do put them in a toolbar, use the ToolButton and let gtk use the theme settings for toolbar icon sizes.

Comment: You can override the icon size constants by setting the `pixel-size` property on the image.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and solved this in C, though I am no Python programmer I can give you a hint at the relevant functions, so you might be able to do your task:

First you create a pixbuf out of a stock Icon with gtk.Widget.render_icon. Then, via gtk.gdk.Pixbuf.scale_simple, you can resize it to any size needed. As last step, you can create an image from this pixbuf and use it for a button.

Works perfectly for me with the corresponding C functions.